# Domain of convergence for a power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I have a homework question that we have not discussed at all how to do in class, so any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated! I don't know where to start.

In each of the following cases, you are given a set of numbers. In each case, determine whether this set of numbers can be a domain of convergence for a power series. If it cannot, explain why it cannot. If it can, give an example of a power series that has this set as its domain of convergence. a. [−1, 3) b. (−1, 3) c. (−1, 3] d. [−1, 3] e. [0, 15) f. [0, 12345) g. [0,∞) h. Q (the set of all rational numbers)

Comment: I suggest that you google on "radius of convergence of power series".

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).